# How to login remotely using SSH

Tags: ssh, openssh

When I'm trying to login remotely using SSH, it asks something like:

```
The authenticity of host '192.168.0.4 (192.168.0.4)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is 64:ec:a0:fa:bf:f0:65:a6:b2:af:90:f2:97:44:e4:3f.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)?
```

What is that, and what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

ssh deals with the log in credentials and the public key for providing access.

the public key is saved in `~/.ssh/known_hosts` file on local machine.

@Nani, what you are getting on the prompt is "you are being asked to save the public key on your local machine."

You need to answer yes, so that the key is saved and it will not ask you again. (Unless the public key of remote machine is changed.)

If public key of the remote machine is changed, you have to remove the previously saved key from the `~/.ssh/known_hosts`

Comment: @Sourav, `/root/..` and `~/..` both are same.

Answer (score 0):

That is just public key is saved in ~/.ssh/known_hosts file on local machine.

Go ahead, type yes, next it will ask for password of 192.168.0.4

Now you are connected to and can access 192.168.0.4